# Image Id is not showing at back end in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am using Repeater control and in it I have one Image tag having id as 'imgGallery'. but in code behind file, I cannot access it.

aspx

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptImage" runat="server">
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Image ID="imgGallery" runat="server" />
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
</div>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (DBDataContext dt = new DBDataContext())
    {
        var frm = from i in dt.GalleryMasters
                  where i.CategoryId == 1
                  select i;
        foreach (var item in frm)
        {
            Image img = (Image)rptImage.FindControl("imgGallery");
            img.ImageUrl = item.Image;
            ((HtmlControl)(FindControl("ifrm"))).Attributes["src"] = item.Video;
        }           
    }
}
```

If I use FindControl then var is null.

Comment: imgGallery is not a part of the repeater in that manner. It's a part of an item within the repeater

Comment: still. it is not accessing anywhere.

Comment: I think you need to look up databinding in asp.net and especially the ItemDataBound event of repeater. Bind a datasource to your repeater, then in it's event, do the FindControl

Comment: if i remove repeater, then also i am not able to find Id of the image.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to bind your repeater:

```
rptImage.DataSource = frm.ToList();
rptImage.DataBind();
```

In your view should be possible to do this:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgGallery" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Video") %>' />
```

In code behind, to get items in your repeater, you need to iterate throught his items. The single item contains your image control. This should work:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptImage.Items) {
    Image img = (Image)item.FindControl("imgGallery");
    // Some other code
}
```

Comment: count in rptImage.Items is 0

Comment: I updated my answare with more things that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind image in Repeater control based on Database result then you can directly assign datasource to Repeater control instead of finding image control.

Also Repeater does not have any record then it will not find any control which is inside the repeater as there is not any row in repeater.